# [Printer][Brother HL-L2350DW] Unable to print. Misc error messages

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

Brother HL-L2350DW | Linux | Ubuntu base

I'm using this printer under Ubuntu (Kubuntu) 18.10.

I've tried installing it via Ubuntu itself (USB connection > Let Ubuntu/Printer find the recommended driver, and use that). Sometimes it have printed, but most of the time not. Was able to print a few pages from Thunderbird and Kate (.txt) yesterday, but then not print a .pdf from Okular. And now it's completely dead again.

The printer throws me error messages like:

- Rendering page 3. (In Printer settings/queue)
- Processing page 2. (In Printer settings/queue)
- Sending to printer (In Printer settings/queue)
- Unable to add document to print job. (In Printer settings/queue)
- Out of memory. (On printer LCD)

I've tried both the Local Printer (USB) and Network Printer, where I've tried all drivers pertaining to the printer, as suggested by Ubuntu and those I've found myself:

- `Recommended Drivers > Brother HL-L2350DW series, driverless, cups-filters 1.21.3`
- `Brother > HLL2350DW for CUPS (en)`
- `Generic Text-Only Printer (en)`

I've even tried to install the drivers from [Brother's website](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2350dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf103566_000&flang=4&type3=10283) (.deb package).

```
§ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  hll2350dwpdrv:i386        4.0.0-1     i386         Brother HL-L2350DW printer driver (lpd/cups)
ii  printer-driver-brlaser    4-1         amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch     1.4.2-3     amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Further, I have to log in* on the CUPS interface for my printer.

> Depending on the connection type you are using (USB or Network), follow one of the steps below.
>
> (for USB Connection)
>
> 1. Open a web browser and go to "http://localhost:631/printers".
> 2. Check if the Device URI of your printer is "usb://Brother/(your printer's model name)"
>
>    - If the device URI is different from the example above, please go to "Modify Printer" of your printer to select proper device and
>        driver.
>    - If your printer is not listed on "http://localhost:631/printers", please go to "http://localhost:631/admin" and click "Add printer" and
>        select proper device and driver.

In here I can't find anywhere to check, and/or correct, the Device URI.

Any ideas or similar experiences? This is gettin really frustrating, to put it mildly.

---

*Log-in information is the same as your user account on your PC. I.e. Finally stumbled upon that information when writing this here post, so this here is for anyone scratching their heads bloody over log-in info, as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Printer Device URI can be read and edited in Ubuntu 16.04LTS here:

1. Open the Printers program however you like ("System Settings" > "Printers", for example).
2. Right-click the printer in question and click "Properties".
3. In the "Settings" is a "Device URI" text input.

However, instead of following the instructions from Brother in your link, I was able to get my HL-L2350DW running just by running [this script from Brother](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hll2350dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625). Complete instructions for unzipping and running the script are available there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your answer to just provide the instructions to find the 'Device URI' and provide more detailed instructions on how to run that script from Brother.

Comment: if you run the script it gives you the option to provide the uri or not, I set it to "usb://Brother/(your printer's model name)" and that works

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Brother HL-L2350DW works with Ubuntu 20.xx. A few things can stop it from working though. You can follow these steps to get it working:

1. Remove all your printers in Ubuntu Settings and restart.
2. Connect the printer to your Wi-Fi setup (I Used WPS in the Brother manual).
3. Turn of your firewall and VPN service if you use one. The printer should pop up in the printers section after a while.(usually 2 of them with different names).
4. Create a test page in LibreOffice or another similar software and send it to the listed printers (that popped up automatically). One of them will work. It's usually the one with ".series" after the name. Mark that one as your default printer and let the others stay in printers section (new ones will pop up all the time otherwise).
5. Set up your UFW firewall and whitelist ports:

   ```
   139/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   445/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   137/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   138/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere

   54925/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere        
   54926/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
   ```

   The last two are vital for Brother printers to connect according to the Brother setup guide.

Printing should work fine if you followed the above.

**Note:** It does NOT work if you are connected to NordVPN though, but that is a NordVPN problem, not an Ubuntu or Brother one.